# Passing user auth status in view

Tags: python, django, cookiecutter-django

I am using Django Cookiecutter as template. And by default in urls.py there is following url:

```
url(r'^about/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='pages/about.html'), name='about'),
```

and because i need to pass some additional parameters in it i wanted to use it as:

```
url(r'^about/$', index, name='about'),
```

Where index is from my views, but when i use the view, my system does not recognise that user is logged in, should i somehow pass user in my index too or what am i doing wrong?

What i am doing in my view:

```
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('pages/about.html', {
        'categories': Category.objects.all(),
        'posts': Post.objects.all()[:5]
    })
```

Comment: Have you written any authentication process for user?

Comment: please elaborate how are you checking the user in the template?

Comment: I guess you have a decorator in the view requiring authentication or something? User data is normally added the to `request` object in middleware.

Comment: All is from boilerplate about authentication. So i don't really require that user is logged in, but when i use view function user object is not passed like it is in TemplateView.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth

Comment: Context processor for auth is there so this is not a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using render instead of render to response so the method after change looks like this:

```
def index(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    posts = Post.objects.all()[:5]
    context = {'categories': categories, 'posts': posts}
    return render(request, 'pages/home.html', context)
```